# why the 'fill=' function doesnt work in boxplot in ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am making boxplot by ggplot2, but I want to divide into two groups, `treated`' and '`control`', so I use '`fill=treatment`', but still one box in each time point,

however, when I use '`fill=treatment`' in barplot, it works,

so can you help me to fix it, really thanks!

```
newcrk10m <- melt(newcrk10,id.vars="time point",variable.name="treatment",
                value.name="value")

ggplot(newcrk10m,aes(`time point`,value,fill=treatment))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,72,24))


ggplot(newcrk10m,aes(x=`time point`,y=value,
  group=`time point`,fill=treatment))+
  geom_boxplot(size=0.5)+scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,72,24))
```

Comment: How many values (numbers) you have per each `time point` and `treatment`?

Comment: three time point,

Comment: i fix it, i paste 'time point' and 'treatment' then make a new df, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i fix it, i paste 'time point' and 'treatment' then make a new df, it works, thanks!